# Can someone clearly paraphrase the following argument?

Tags: probability, self-study, order-statistics

[Metaculus](https://www.metaculus.com/questions/) is a site where users make and justify predictions on various questions.

My question is about an estimation of the probability that a human will live to 120 years by the year 2024. I am hoping that someone can clearly paraphrase the following paragraph ([source](https://www.metaculus.com/questions/348/will-one-of-the-verified-oldest-living-persons-in-the-world-reach-120-years-old-by-the-23rd-of-march-2024/#)) so that it is understandable by an advanced undergraduate:

> Perhaps a more rigorous derivation is to draw uniformly at random from
>   the inverse CDF. We don't know the inverse CDF, but whole idea here is
>   that we are interested only in ranks, and the inverse CDF is
>   monotonically increasing! So we simply draw n samples uniformly at
>   random from [0, 1] and consider the largest to be Calment [the longest-living human, who died at 122] and 2nd
>   Knauss [the second longest-living human, who died at 119]. Our cutoff for positive resolution is then drawn uniformly at
>   random between these two. We can see this cutoff as the chances of the
>   nth all-time oldest person (who is living) reaching the cutoff.
>   Calment and Knauss follow the 1st and 2nd order statistics of n draws
>   from [0, 1], and after some calculation it turns out that the final
>   expression is exactly what we have above!